# Minecraft Datapacks functions not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

I use 1.14.4 and when I put datapacks in the server, I can't find the functions and they don't appear or work when I manually put them in.

I am using a home hosted server and am trying to get datapacks working.

The file specified is this: `pc-documents-server-world-datapacks-datapack`

Comment: If this is a datapack you downloaded, make sure that in your datapacks folder in your world, there is one folder per datapack, and each datapack folder has a 'data' folder and a 'pack.mcmeta' file directly inside it. If there's a resourcepack included, make sure you take it out and put it in the resource packs folder.

Comment: I did, when I do /datapack list active and they all show up, but when I put in /function ____ nothing shows up

Comment: So nothing comes up in the auto fill? Go into the data folder for one of them and there should be several folders inside. That is a namespace. Try typing in that namespace in the `/function` command and see if some auto fill option becomes available. If it doesn't, the functions must be invalid. Go into the namespace folder and into the functions folder inside. Open one of the function files (they end with .mcfunction) and make sure all of the commands inside are valid, either by manually checking them, or pasting them in mc one by one. Maybe put them in your question?

Comment: Could you put links to all of the datapacks which you are trying to install?

Comment: https://www.planetminecraft.com/mod/blood-moon-remastered/
https://www.planetminecraft.com/mod/accumula-town-datapck/
https://www.planetminecraft.com/mod/datapack-betterfurnace-1-13-x/
https://www.planetminecraft.com/mod/creeper-aww-man-achievement/
https://www.planetminecraft.com/mod/xxceezxx-recipes-v1/
https://www.planetminecraft.com/mod/graves-1-13/
https://www.planetminecraft.com/mod/spawners-4345577/
Here are the datapacks im using

Comment: Edit them into your question and delete the comment, so it's easier to see them for other people. Also, using datapacks for 1.13 is risky on 1.14 because a few things that changed could mess up a lot of things. Also, are the data and mcmeta files in accumulatown? Or are they another folder down?

Comment: They are directly in the folder in datapacks

Comment: I'll test them when I get back to my computer and get back to you.

Comment: Fixed the datapacks so there is no need to test

Comment: Thank you for your help and have a good day. :)

Comment: No problem. If you know what you did to fix it, answer your own question with whatever you did so other people with the same question can also find a solution.